# How to get the same JSON structure as in full object retrieval when querying only for part of the properties using JSON.GET Redis?

Tags: redis

Looking for a code to get only several properties of JSON object (RedisJson) that:

1. Will return the same JSON structure as returned in whole object retrieval
2. Will be tolerant to missing properties

For example, store a Redis.Json object

```
JSON.SET Cat:1 $'{"name":"Mitzi", "color":"pink", "age":1}'
```

Get the whole object

```
JSON.GET Cat:1
```

Result:

```
"{\"name\":\"Mitzi\",\"color\":\"pink\",\"age\":1}"
```

Now we would like to retrieve only properties "name", "color", and "food" (missing).
Expected result:

```
"{\"name\":\"Mitzi\",\"color\":\"pink\"}"
```

or maybe:

```
"{\"food\":\"\",\"name\":\"Mitzi\",\"color\":\"pink\"}"
```

We try this: (will be referred as "method1")

```
JSON.GET Cat:1 $.name $.color $.food
```

However, we actually get a different structure that is later failed  to be deserialized:

```
"{\"$.food\":[],\"$.name\":[\"Mitzi\"],\"$.color\":[\"pink\"]}"
```

Compared to the expected structure, the differences are:

1. There is the "$." sign before the property name
2. There are square brackets around the value

When we try another method (will be referred as "method2")

```
JSON.GET Cat:1 name color
```

We indeed receive the expected JSON structure:

```
"{\"name\":\"Mitzi\",\"color\":\"pink\"}"
```

However, "method2" returns an error in case a property is missing (in contrast to "method1" ).

```
JSON.GET Cat:1 name color food
```

Returns:
"ERR Path 'food' does not exist"

The question is: what is the syntax to is there a method that tolerates missing properties and still returns JSON in our expected format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 3rd option if the JSON fields are at the same hierarchy,
however missing fields are skipped, so it might not be possible to distinguish between missing and existing fields, for example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET Cat:1 '$["name","color","food"]'
"[\"Mitzi\",\"pink\"]"
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET Cat:1 '$["name","food","color"]'
"[\"Mitzi\",\"pink\"]"
```

(If, for example, `orange` can be either color or food - the result might be ambiguous)

Regarding "method1", this is the only way to get unambiguous multiple values
and the `$` denotes the root of the JSON document (See [JSONPath syntax][1]).
Regarding the square brackets around the value, this is actually returning an array of values, since a JSONPath may match multiple values within a JSON document, for example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET Cat:2 $ '{"names":[{"lang":"EN", "name":"Mitzi"},{"lang":"DE-CH","name":"Musli"}], "color":"pink", "age":1}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET Cat:2 '$.names[*].name' color food
"{\"color\":[\"pink\"],\"food\":[],\"$.names[*].name\":[\"Mitzi\",\"Musli\"]}"
```

(a missing field is a key in the returned map with an empty array as its value)

"method2" is using [legacy JSONPath](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/path/#legacy-path-syntax) (starting with an optional `.`) which matches RedisJSON 1.x behavior and might be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but you might also find indexing JSON data using RediSearch, which can perform queries and project fields, such as `FT.SEARCH itemIdx '@description:(headphones)' RETURN 5 name price $.stock AS stock`. See https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/indexing_json/#project-with-jsonpath